# Script Query only outputting 2nd half of formula

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm building a master sheet of many ever-changing tabs, and have written some script code that is meant to pull cells based on what time it is using if/else. When I run the script, it only outputs the tail end of the Query: "***=",0),{"","","","","","","","","","","","","",""}))***"

I'm not sure why it's able to pull that section of the query, but skips over the other 2 sections.

Here's what I have:

```
function masterSheetTimes() {
  const armingTimesQuery = "$B225:$O225";
  const sunTimesQueryList = "col1, col8";

  var date = new Date();  
  var hrs = date.getHours();
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const allSheets = ss.getSheets(); 

  let formulaArray = filteredListOfSheets.map(s => `${s.getSheetName()}'!${armingTimesQuery};'` + `${s.getSheetName()}'!${disarmingTimesQuery}`);
  let formulaTextfront = `=ArrayFormula(IFERROR(QUERY({'` + formulaArray.join(";'") + `},"select `;
  let formulaTextback = `",0),{"","","","","","","","","","","","","",""}))`;

  if((date.getDay() == 0) && (hrs >= 9) || (date.getDay() == 1) && (hrs <= 9)){
  ss.getSheetByName(masterSheet).getRange(masterSheetFormulaCell).setFormula(formulaTextfront).setFormula(sunTimesQueryList).setFormula(formulaTextback);
  } 

  else if((date.getDay() == 6) && (hrs >= 9)){
  ss.getSheetByName(masterSheet).getRange(masterSheetFormulaCell).setFormula(formulaTextfront).setFormula(satTimesQueryList).setFormula(formulaTextback);
  } else {
  ss.getSheetByName(masterSheet).getRange(masterSheetFormulaCell).setValue("Script Error");
  }

}
```

[Here's a sample sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1E4cPIqLckUU9y1Zssh7L3AxxOYTsOhrJtHC-XkFfR3Q/edit?usp=sharing)
Row 3 (in green) is an example of what output should look like. L4 (in yellow) is where the query should be placed.

This is the line where the formula should be called, but it is only outputting the last section of the formula "***(formulaTextback)***".

```
ss.getSheetByName(masterSheet).getRange(masterSheetFormulaCell).setFormula(formulaTextfront).setFormula(satTimesQueryList).setFormula(formulaTextback)
```

Any help and/or suggestions on where the error is welcome. If there's a more efficient way to do this, would also love to hear, as this is all an attempt to cut down loading time.

Comment: Unclear what was impossible to read (as it displays fine on my end), and/or what was different within the link you sent. Upon reading it, it looked as though I followed how to place the formula(?). I sectioned things out a bit in case that makes it more clear, and brought out the specific section I *think*(?) needs help. It also doesn't look different than other posts I've read? Not sure what else to do.

Comment: Try his: `ss.getSheetByName(masterSheet).getRange(masterSheetFormulaCell).setFormula(formulaTextfront + monTimesQueryList +  formulaTextback);`  or Use Utilities.formatString();

Comment: Nice! That also worked, ty!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the setFormula method three times in a row. Google Sheets is only using the last formula you set so in .setFormula(formulaTextfront).setFormula(monTimesQueryList).setFormula(formulaTextback); - only setFormula(formulaTextback) is being written to the cell.

You can't join the variables like this. I think you need to write a new variable concatenating your three formulas and then use that variable to setFormula method. So it would be something like:

```
var myFormula = formulaTextfront + monTimesQueryList + formulaTextback;
ss.getSheetByName(masterSheet).getRange(masterSheetFormulaCell).setFormula(myFormula);
```